# OCaml: Function application with labelled and optional arguments

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a function that has the `x` as an optional argument and `y,z` as labelled arguments. Say the format is like `concat1`. I realized that when I try to do `concat1 y:"hello" z:"world"` it doesn't actually apply the function, it returns a function instead.

```
let concat1 ?(x = " ") ~y ~z = y ^x ^ z
let concat2 ?(x = " ") y z = y ^x ^z
let concat3 ?(x = " ") y ~z = y ^ x ^z
let concat4 ?(x = " ") ~y z =
```

The results of applying these different forms are

```
concat1 ~y:"hello ~z:"world" -> ?x:string -> string <fun>
concat1 "hello" "world" -> "hello world"
concat2 "hello" "world" -> "hello world"

concat3 "hello" -> z:string -> string = <fun>
concat4 "world" -> y:string -> string = <fun>
```

How do I get `concat1` to execute? I don't want to call the function without labelled arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the text from the [language definition](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html):

> If a non-labeled argument is passed, and its corresponding parameter is preceded by one or several optional parameters, then these parameters are *defaulted*, i.e. the value `None` will be passed for them. All other missing parameters (without corresponding argument), both optional and non-optional, will be kept, and the result of the function will still be a function of these missing parameters to the body of f.

It follows that you need to supply at least one non-labelled argument if you want optional arguments to be defaulted. Since your `concat1` function has no non-labeled arguments, this isn't possible.

An idiom I've seen for functions with lots of labelled and optional arguments is to have a final unit argument:

```
let concat1 ?(x = " ") ~y ~z () = y ^ x ^ z
```

Then you can easily supply a non-labeled argument to get defaulting of the optional ones.

```
# let concat1 ?(x = " ") ~y ~z () = y ^ x ^ z;;
val concat1 : ?x:string -> y:string -> z:string -> unit -> string = <fun>
# concat1 ~y: "abc" ~z: "def" ();;
- : string = "abc def"
```

I'm not sure if this works for you.

Comment: I personally find labeled arguments messy by default, to be used sparingly. Write the label and argument without spaces. One good use IMO is in config functions that take a lot of labeled arguments with meaningful names, and you write them each on one line.

Comment: I've found labelled arguments to be more trouble than they're worth in all programming languages. If the arguments get too complicated, I'd rather replace by a data structure. I never use them in my own OCaml code. Just one guy's opinion.